# sed -n command or variable substitution

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to substitute `date` command in `sed`.

As shown below, I'm trying boh command & variable substitution but neither of the approaches produce output. I've tried a few things of which I'm posting below the one that doesn't error out.

```
sed -n "/$(date -d '1 year ago' '+%Y-%m')/,$p" filename.csv

search=$(date -d "1 year ago" '+%Y-%m')
sed -ne '/"${search}"/,$p' filename.csv
```

How could I substitute either  a variable or a command into `sed` please?

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Comment: If you use `"` for `bash` `$p` is a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -n '/'"$(date -d "1 year ago" '+%Y-%m')"'/,$p' filename.csv
```